# Textbox Change Event not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, json

I have two Textboxes,I'm trying to fill the Second Textbox at change Event of Textbox1

Eg:
I have to fill the Customer Name when i type the Customer Code at TextBox1.

MY Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        userCodeChangeEvent();

    });


function userCodeChangeEvent() {

    $('#<%=txtCustomerCode.ClientID %>').change(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Customer_Bill.aspx/GetNameByCode",
            data: "{'CusName':'" + document.getElementById('<%=txtCustomerCode.ClientID %>').value + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                $('#<%=txtcustomerName.ClientID %>').value = data.d; 

            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("No Match");
            }
        });


    });
}
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetNameByCode(string CusName)
{
   // List<string> empResult = new List<string>();
    string empResult = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select user_name From tbl_member_Registration where user_code=@SearchEmpName";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchEmpName", CusName);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                empResult=dr["user_name"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
            return empResult;
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't working .How do i Solve this?

Comment: Have you checked the resulting HTML to see whether the ClientID is the expected ID (the same as the ID of the textbox) or not? Have you used a debugger to see where the problem lies (in the event itself or in the AJAX call)?

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart The Problem at Ajax Call ,I checked alert box with Change function and it works . also I set Breakpoint in C# code but it doestn't Invoked

Answer (score 6):

**I**n client side 2 things you should notice :

1- `$(...).val(data.d);`

2- use "`keyup`" instead "`change`" because change will not be fired while the user is typing.

**I**n Server side make sure that you enabled "ScriptService" by adding the `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` attribute to the web service class (code behind the asmx) as the following:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetNameByCode(string CusName)
    {
      ...
    }

}
```

Comment: The Problem at Ajax Call ,I checked alert box with Change function and it works . also I set Breakpoint in C# code but it doestn't Invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` function use `val()` instead of `val=` like this

```
success: function(data) {

$('#<%=txtcustomerName.ClientID %>').val(data.d); 

}
```

,

And if necessary change this line also

```
data: "{'CusName':'" + $('#<%=txtCustomerCode.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
```

Comment: `val()` not `value()` ;)

Comment: You probably mean `val()`, not `value()`.

Comment: or this `$('#<%=txtcustomerName.ClientID %>').get(0).value = data.d; `

Comment: @King_Fisher is there any error shown while debugging js?

Comment: @صفي TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Comment: @صفي The Problem at Ajax Call ,I checked alert box with Change function and it works . also I set Breakpoint in C# code but it doestn't Invoked

Comment: @King_Fisher if you are using `live()` with jQuery greater than 1.7 then it will not work.`change()` will work with above 1.7.

Comment: @صفي I have above 1.7 ...<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @King_Fisher  where are you using `live()`?

Comment: @صفي I don't have that function in my Script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68722/discussion-between--and-king-fisher).